# Facebook: Updating page tabs through Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to update my tab on a series of pages on facebook. Due to the volume of pages I'm making batch calls to keep from being rate limited. The batch calls work fine.

That being said, I'm trying to Update a page tab by making the call as stated [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs). I have the adding functionality working fine, and it's operating as it should. I use the same method of getting and using tokens, and I know moreso that it's not an issue as I have offline access so they don't expire (I get them every page load, but in reality could just store them and not worry about it).

Both calls use the same page ID, app ID, and access token and the call is good. The Error I receive is that the tab does not exist on the page, yet when I go to https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID my tab is there showing itself as on the page. When I post to that I get the error it's not there.

My question is this: Has anyone gotten this working yet and if so what did your call look like and am I missing something?

I would post code, but it's incredibly long and intertwined in my program so it would be difficult to extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight issue with the page tabs API at the moment that means in some situations you need to prepend your app id in the call with `app_` so `/PAGE_ID/tabs/app_APP_ID`, give this a try and see if it works.